# cmd does not work property for C project

Tags: c, cmd

[image]

According to my project char. s should change to o, but in cmd it just shows 4.

Comment: please post code instead of screen shots!!!

Answer (score 1):

Your code is kind of undefined behaviour...

you are doing this:

```
name[12] = "o";
```

which is actually assigning a string "o" to a place where a char must be....

you mean  'o' for sure...

```
name[12] = 'o';
```

Comment: yeah u r right! thnx (@"@)

Comment: : ) you are welcome! @yasFarhang